# Change url new tab page default for Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, registry

I am working with Internet Explorer. I know how to change the home page or default search engine by changing the registry, but I don't understand how some programs (e.g. *Baidu PC Faster*, *Search Protect*) change the URL of a new tab page. Homepage remains unique, new tab page doesn't read homepage

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "some programs"? Perhaps you can you give a few examples?

Comment: I *think* these programs hook into Internet Explorer by using its plugin API (listening to IE's events), but that's just a guess.

Comment: I used to think the same but when I killed these programs in processes IE was working with changed URL of a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

To change the internet explorer default page you have to change the key [Start Page] in the path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

Use this code to do that

```
        RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", true);
        myKey.SetValue("Start Page", "www.google.com", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't say that I should be able to put a different addresses for the home page and a new tab

Comment: what about windows security how to ignore it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AboutURLs\Tabs` registry key.

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AboutURLs", true);
myKey.SetValue("Tabs", "www.YourURL.com", RegistryValueKind.String);
```